# How to create a gaussian blur effect in libGDX without shaders

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, blur

How do you create a gaussian blur effect without any shaders? I tried many shader tutorials but I never got it to work. I also tried this link. https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/OpenGL-ES-Blurs
But, I couldn't get the screen to be transformed into a pixmap. Can you guys point me in the right direction on where to go to get the right answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need real-time blur, it has to be done with shaders. If speed doesn't matter, you could convolve a Pixmap, but there's no built-in way. You would have to iterate the pixels ByteBuffer to convolve it.

Answer (score 0):

To draw blur without shaders you would need to draw the original scene to some texture. Then draw this texture NxN times on your main buffer with some blending. Alpha must correspond to the factor that depends on the offset in the NxN matrix. Just as pseudo:

```
for(int heightDiff=-N; heightDiff<=N; heightDiff++) {
    for(int widthDiff=-N; widthDiff<=N; widthDiff++) {
       float alpha = 1.0/max(width, height); // Not a correct equation
       glColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha):
       drawFullscreenWithOffset(widthDiff, heightDiff);
    }
}
```

It might be an optimization to separate vertical and horizontal blur though. That would mean you need to choose one of them and draw it to a new texture and then use that one to draw the other blur on the main buffer. You gain an extra texture but you reduce NxN draws to 2*N.